# SQL Report Query To DataGrid

Tags: sql, datagrid, report

I'm trying to run a SQL report Query and get the result to a datagrid. My query works in SSMS, but in my code I get errors complaining about a '(' and 'as' I've gone through the code but can't seem to find the error.

Here is the part with the query:

```
myCmd = New SqlCommand("Declare @StartDate datetime," & _
"@StopDate datetime, " & _
"@location float; " & _
"set @StartDate='" & DateF & "'" & _
"set @StopDate='" & DateT & "'" & _
"set @Location = '1'" & _
"SELECT " & _
"MAX(CASE WHEN [Purchases].[Type]=1 OR [Purchases].[Type]=2 THEN -1 ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar,[LEVEL1].[Department Number]) END) as 'Department Number', " & _
"MAX(CASE WHEN [Purchases].[Type]=1 OR [Purchases].[Type]=2 THEN 'Unallocated'ELSE ISNULL([LEVEL1].[Department Name],'Deleted') END) as 'Department Name', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Opening],0)) as 'Opening', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Goods Received],0)) as 'Goods Received', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Claims],0)) as 'Claims', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Goods Received/Claim],0)) as 'Goods Received/Claim', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Sales],0)) as 'Sales', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Consumed],0)) as 'Consumed', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Produced],0)) as 'Produced', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Produced/Consumed],0)) as 'Produced/Consumed', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Transfered],0)) as 'Transferred', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Adjusted],0)) as 'Adjusted', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Accepted],0)) as 'Accepted', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Cost Adjustment],0)) as 'Cost Adjustment', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Closing],0)) as 'Closing', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_Sales Journal].[Gross Sales (Excl)],0)) as 'Gross Sales (Excl)', " & _
"SUM(isnull(Purchases.[Nett Purchase Value],0)) as 'Nett Cost Adjustment (Excl)', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_StockMovement].[Opening],0) - isnull([View_StockMovement].[Closing],0) + isnull(Purchases.[Nett Purchase Value],0)) " & _
"as 'Operating Cost', " & _
"SUM(isnull([View_Sales Journal].[Gross Sales (Excl)],0) - (isnull([View_StockMovement].[Opening],0) - isnull([View_StockMovement].[Closing],0) + isnull(Purchases.[Nett Purchase Value],0))) " & _
"as 'Gross Operating Profit', " & _
"SUM(isnull([Cost Adjustment System],0)) as [Cost Adjustment System], " & _
"SUM(isnull([Cost Adjustment User], 0)) as [Cost Adjustment User] " & _
"From [product details] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN [department details] as [LEVEL5] ON [LEVEL5].[department number]=[Product Details].[Department Number] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN [department details] as [LEVEL4] ON [LEVEL4].[Department Number]=[LEVEL5].[Reporting Department] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN [department details] as [LEVEL3] ON [LEVEL3].[Department Number]=[LEVEL4].[Reporting Department] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN [department details] as [LEVEL2] ON [LEVEL2].[Department Number]=[LEVEL3].[Reporting Department] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN [department details] as [LEVEL1] ON [LEVEL1].[Department Number]=[LEVEL2].[Reporting Department] " & _
"FULL(Join) " & _
"(SELECT [Type], [Product Code], " & _
"SUM([Nett Purchase Value]) AS 'Nett Purchase Value' " & _
"FROM dbo.fn_Table_PurchaseSummary(@StartDate, @StopDate,-1,-1,-1,-1) as [Consolidated] " & _
"GROUP BY [Consolidated].[Type],[Consolidated].[Product Code]) as [Purchases] ON [Product Details].[Product Code] = [Purchases].[Product Code] AND 0 = [Purchases].[Type] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
"(SELECT [Sales Journal].[Product Code], " & _
"sum([Sales Journal].[Line Total] - [Sales Journal].[Sales Tax]) as 'Gross Sales (Excl)' " & _
"From [Sales Journal] WITH (NOLOCK) " & _
"WHERE [Sales Journal].[Function Key] in (4,5,6,7,8) AND [Sales Journal].[Date & _ Time] > @StartDate AND [Sales Journal].[Date & _ Time] < @StopDate " & _
"GROUP BY [Sales Journal].[Product Code]) as 'View_Sales Journal' ON [View_Sales Journal].[Product Code]=[Product Details].[Product Code] " & _
"LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.fn_Table_StockMovement(@StartDate, @StopDate, @Location) as 'View_StockMovement' ON [product details].[product code]=[View_StockMovement].[product code] " & _
"WHERE (isnull(convert(tinyint, [Product Details].[Deleted]), 0) <> 1 AND " & _
"((isnull([View_StockMovement].[Opening],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Goods Received],0) <> 0 or " & _
"isnull([View_StockMovement].[Claims],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Goods Received/Claim],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Sales],0) <> 0 or " & _
"isnull([View_StockMovement].[Consumed],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Produced],0) <> 0 or " & _
"isnull([View_StockMovement].[Produced/Consumed],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Transfered],0) <> 0 or " & _
"isnull([View_StockMovement].[Adjusted],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Accepted],0) <> 0 or " & _
"isnull([View_StockMovement].[Cost Adjustment],0) <> 0 or isnull([View_StockMovement].[Closing],0) <> 0))) " & _
"GROUP BY [LEVEL1].[Department Number], isnull([Purchases].[Type], 0) ORDER BY [Department Name]", myConn)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you post "why doesn't this work?" questions, it's important to give as much information as possible and as little code as possible. What people want to see is a minimally reproducible chunk of code with the error message that accompanies it. You can get more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Try editing your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Missing a trailing space on this line? This causes the query to run into the SELECT statement

```
"set @Location = '1'" & _
```